# Is it possible to extract url from hyperlinks in excel if it's setup like this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, hyperlink, extract

I have few hundred lines like this in excel file.  I have tried to copy them one by one and it's very tiresome; so I am wondering if there is a away to extract the urls from all of them at once?

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/link?id=SsQD2GsCjgY&offerid=445126&mid-heel-sandal-black"><IMG border=0 src="https://e31vejvoh8fjtd.bi/catalog/product/1/0/1039-000064-2412-2.jpg" ></a><IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 src="http://ad.fjuyla.com/fs-bin/show?id=SsQD2GsCjgY&bids=445126.3671510716&type=2&subid=0" >
```

Note*: I mean the main href url, not the src url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Formula if all URLs look the same:
`=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1,1)+2,FIND(">",A1,1)-FIND("=",A1,1)-3)`
It extract the middle text between the first `=` and the first `>`
A1 is the reference where your data is located
The first Find will give the place of = + 2 where the h of http starts
The second Find will give the place -1  of > end of the URL
The difference between the two find for the length of the URL
and you can copy this formula.

[image]

Comment: Cool. Now I am kind of a noob at Excel.  How do I apply that formula to all the links?

Comment: Write or copy your links to column A and write this formula in column B and copy it down in front of the links you will have the result in column B

Comment: I have all the links in Column A and the formula in Column B. I dragged it down so that there is a formula for each link row.  Nothing happens. No results show up in Column B.

Comment: is your links in one cell only

Comment: All links are in separate cells. So for eg. 20 links in 20 cells with Column A with href links and Column B with the formulas. Does it work on your Excel?

Comment: I copied your example and paste it in A1 and used the formula in B1 and got: `**http://mywebsite.com/link?id=SsQD2GsCjgY&offerid=445126&mid-heel-sandal-black**`

Comment: Try writing the formula with fx not copy paste maybe your settings are different

Comment: Ah yes. writing the formula fixed the problem.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually I found out what I was doing wrong.  After copying the formula in the formula field, I had to press ENTER for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines all contain

```
<a href=" ...... "><IMG
```

You could use regex to filter by that.
For how to use regex in excel, look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops